# Using Makers Array in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For my laboratory project, I have to use markers arrays in rviz to show the movement of satellites around the globe. The parameters of satellites are changing constantly. I have to represent every satellite in spherical coordinates for 3D movement. I have successfully been able to publish all the 3 parameters of every satellite on a topic "menutopic". Now I do not know how can I represent the satellites as markers array in rviz with constantly changing parameters.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73051/using-makers-array-in-rviz/) by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a [good tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes) on Markers on the ros.org wiki; make sure to go through that first.

Some things to watch out for in general (otherwise the markers won't be displayed):

- set the alpha value (`marker.color.a`) to something non-zero
- you have to specify a valid quaternion as orientation (e.g., `marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0`)

Some more specific answers to your question:

- You need to convert the spherical coordinates into a geometry_msgs/PoseStamped, and put that into `marker.pose`.
- You can either publish each marker in an individual message and publish them on some topic of type `visualization_msgs/Marker`, or put several of them into a MarkerArray and publish them on a topic of type `visualization_msgs/MarkerArray`. The latter is more efficient than the former, but for your use case either should work.
- Constantly updating the position of each satellite works like this: You set the namespace of all markers to the same namespace (e.g., `marker.ns = "satellites"`), and give each satellite a unique id (e.g., `marker.id = 23`). Whenever you want to update the pose of a marker, just publish another Marker message with the same id (it will overwrite the previous one). Even if nothing changes, you should re-publish all existing markers regularly.

In order to add text/name to a marker in RViz, just add a second marker of type TEXT_VIEW_FACING and fill out the `text` property.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-01-25**:
TEXT_VIEW_FACING does not display the text